# mpi.h not found

Tags: compiling, eclipse, header-file, mpi

I tried to compile the Hello World program in C, inside Eclipse PTP, but it gives me an error related to `mpi.h`.

I have included `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` in my paths, and also tried running a search with `find / -name mpi.h`. I still get a *No such file or directory* error.

I tried to install `mpich2`, but still couldn't find `mpi.h`.

Also:

- There is no folder inside the `include` directory, why is that?
- I can find `mpicc` at `/usr/bin/mpicc`

The same problem occurs when trying to compile the project as C++ code. What should I do?

Comment: What OS? You probably don't have something like the mpi-devel or such package installed that includes the headers.

Comment: centos 6.7 

i use eclipse PTP ( parallel Tool Plateform )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This Stack Overflow question answers yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133495/how-do-i-find-which-rpm-package-supplies-a-file-im-looking-for).

According to `yum`, the `mpi.h` header file is provided by the following packages:

```
$ yum whatprovides '*/mpi.h'
openmpi-devel-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
mpich2-devel-1.2.1-2.3.el6.x86_64
mvapich2-devel-2.0rc1-1.el6.x86_64
mvapich-devel-1.2.0-0.3563.rc1.5.el6.x86_64
mvapich2-psm-devel-2.0rc1-1.el6.x86_64
mpich-devel-3.1-4.el6.x86_64
mvapich-psm-devel-1.2.0-0.3563.rc1.5.el6.x86_64
```

I've removed most of the output, as well as the `i686` versions. Pick the package according to what (variant) you're trying to work with. :)

Note that most of these packages create  a subdirectory in `/usr/include` when installed. For instance, the `mpi.h` file provided by `openmpi-devel` is available at `/usr/include/openmpi-x86_64/mpi.h`, meaning you'd have to either include `openmpi-x86_64/mpi.h` in your source code, or add the `/usr/include/openmpi-x86_64` directory to your include paths.

Also: some of these packages (such as `mvapich-devel`) don't even use `/usr/include` at all, and put their headers under `/usr/lib64/{package}/include/`.

Answer (score 0):

First, install the mpi using the following command:

**sudo apt install mpich**

**sudo apt install libopenmpi-dev**

Next, check where the library is installed using:

**mpicc -show**

Finally, add the library where it is installed in your code like,

**#include </usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include/openmpi/mpi.h>**

Hope this will help you, thanks in advance!!!